# raw sql on azure server; how do I retrieve the results from a SELECT statement?

Tags: azure

I am doing this statement:

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM [User]";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                results.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }

        var x = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Console.WriteLine("Row retrieved successfully.");
    }
```

It succseeds but I am only getting the columns in order of the "GetString()". How can I put this into my object?

How can I fix this?

Anyone could help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me with below code, have made changes to your code.

```
try
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM [User]";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        List<User> results = new List<User>();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                 while (reader.Read())
                 {
                     User user = new User();                     
                     user.Id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Id"));
                     user.Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name"));                       user.Email = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Email"));
                     results.Add(user);
                  }
             }

             Console.WriteLine("Rows retrieved successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error retrieving rows: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
```

Create a `new User object` for each row returned by the query and use the `Get()` methods to retrieve the values of each column and store them in the object.

And add the `object to a List<User>` to store all the rows returned from the query.

[image]

Comment: Yes perfect! I just also wanna add that If you for instance have a bytearray that is returned (eg profile picture) this is what you would do: Thumbnail = (byte[])reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Thumbnail"))